# Jquery dynamically adding classes

Tags: jquery, html

Hi im working with a mask plugin and I need to add a class to an input level element, however I can't seem to target it correctly, and `.next()` simply goes on to the next level `<td>`.

Here is a [Jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SnDCB/62/) I'm working on as you can see I need the `phone_us` part to be added dynamically to the class attribute because im masking it`<input type="text" class="" name="" value="">`

### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('td').each(function (index) {
   var divHTML =  $(this).text();  

if(divHTML.indexOf("Phone") >= 0)
     {
    $(this).next().css('background-color', 'blue');       
    $(this).next().closest('input').addClass('phone_us');
    $('.phone_us').mask('(999) 999-9999');
     }
});
});
```

### HTML

```
<td class="label">Phone #</td>
<td class="field"><input type="text" class="label_box" name="" value=""></td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.closest()` selects the closest matching parent/grandparent... of the selected element:

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Use `find` or `children` method instead:

```
$('td:contains("Phone")').next()
                         .css('background-color', 'blue')       
                         .find('input')
                         .addClass('phone_us')
                         .mask('(999) 999-9999');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dyNZg/

Comment: I see. Is next() any different then each() is this context?

Comment: @Undermine2k No, there is no difference, it selects the very next  sibling of the selected elements.